# Basic Laravel 5.4 Request Validation not working

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request, laravel-5.4

my problem is that validate method is not validating and same problem with any validate request among my app. any suggestions please ?!

And here is part of AuthenticatesUsers:

```
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request; use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

trait AuthenticatesUsers {

public function login(Request $request) {
$this->validateLogin($request);

if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
    $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

    return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
}

if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
    return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}
$this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}

protected function validateLogin(Request $request) {
$this->validate($request, [
    $this->username() => 'required|string',
    'password' => 'required|string',
]);
}

protected function attemptLogin(Request $request) {
return $this->guard()->attempt(
                $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
);
}

protected function credentials(Request $request) {
return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
}

protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request) {
$errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];

if ($request->expectsJson()) {
    return response()->json($errors, 422);
}

return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
                ->withErrors($errors);
}

public function username() {
return 'email';
}

protected function guard() {
return Auth::guard();
}
}
```

Comment: replace ($this->validateLogin($request);)  with below code : 
$validator = \Validator::make(
            [
                'username' =>  $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password
            ],
            [
                'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
                'password' => 'required|min:6'
            ]
        );

Comment: thanks bro.actually the whole issue was in the Kernel.php i was adding  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class in protected $middleware array and again it is in protected $middlewareGroups ... and the whole idea was because am working with translation using middleware and sessions ... again thanks for ur help

Comment: @KarimHazem Thank you for correction, placing into protected $middlewareGroups = [ 'web' => [ \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,]] helps.